# Blocking a plugins command from displaying in chat and console when run from command block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I am trying to create a timer for a mini game I am working on by using a plugin called Multiple Scoreboards. The plugin basically lets you display different scoreboards to different players, so I am having it display a timer scoreboard to only the players in the minigame.

The way that I am running the timer is by subtracting 1 point every second from a player called Time_Left that is displayed on the sidebar. *However, the command block that is subtracting a point every second is displaying the command it's running in both the chat of the oped players and the console.*

**Is there a way I can block this command from being shown to the console and oped players when it is run by a command block?**

Thanks,
Jonny

Answer (score 1):

The commands `/gamerule commandBlockOutput false` and `/gamerule logAdminCommands false` should work. The first command blocks the output from chat, and the second blocks it from logging.

Comment: I'd like to add /gamerule sendCommandFeedback false, which determines whether commands in the chat are shown. Sometimes command blocks put the results in the chat that way.